# Why is Dash to panel in 17.10 replaced by Ubuntu Dock at each logon?

Tags: gnome-shell-extension, ubuntu-dock

Fresh 17.10 install on bare metal, installed Dash to Panel from extensions.gnome.org.

It works as expected when first activated, but it gets deactivated and replaced by Ubuntu Dock at each logon.

Any idea how to prevent Dash to Panel from being switched off at each logoff?

Answer (score 0):

Just found the culprit... It's the "Extensions" extension from extensions.gnome.org. If it's active, for some reason it restores the previous choice of dock after each logoff. Switched it off and I can now stay with the dock I choose.